# Countable versus uncountable dense linear orders

Tags: first-order-logic, order-theory, automorphism-group, well-orders

Let $(\Omega,\leq)$ be a dense linear order without endpoints.
If $\Omega$ is countable, we know by Cantor that $(\Omega,\leq)$ is order-isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$.

Suppose that $\Omega$ is not countable. In case of $\mathbb{Q}$, we know that for any two ordered sequences $s$ and $\widetilde{s}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, there is an order-isomorphism which sends $s$ to $\widetilde{s}$. (Call this property (IND).)

Is this property also true for uncountable $\Omega$ ?

Secondly, Cantor used a Back-and-Forth argument to prove the aforementioned result. Is there an uncountable variation of this technique (for instance, using transfinite induction) ?

Comment: Definitely not - consider for example $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}+\mathbb{Q}$, and the long line.

Comment: (IND) is not clear: there is no order-isomorphism between the two sequences in $\mathbb Q$ of positive and negative integers. Moreover, do you want to have an order-isomorphism just between the two sequences, or of the whole space, which maps one sequence to the other?

Answer (score 1):

As Noah's comment points out, the Cantor theorem does not generalize quite so directly.

However, Hausdorff found a generalization in his notion of an $\eta$-set (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%97_set)). $(R,<)$ is an $\eta_\alpha$ set if $|R|=\aleph_\alpha$, and given any two subsets $X<Y$ of $R$, each of cardinality less than $\aleph_\alpha$, there is a $u\in R$ with $X<u<Y$. (By $X<Y$, I mean all elements of $X$ are less than all elements of $Y$).

The generalization of the Cantor result reads: if $A,B\subset R$ with $|A|=|B|<\aleph_\alpha$, and there is an order-preserving map $A\to B$, then this map can be extended to an order-preserving bijection of $R$ to itself. This is proved by a transfinite back-and-forth argument, just like you suggested.

Nowadays Hausdorff's $\eta$ sets are considered one of the earliest examples of [saturated structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_model).

Incidentally, the back-and-forth argument [isn't due to Cantor](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/review-of-modern-logic/volume-4/issue-1/Who-invented-Cantors-back-and-forth-argument/rml/1204835164.full): he proved his theorem with a one-way argument. It was that same Hausdorff who invented the back-and-forth method.

Comment: Thank you for this information (that's exactly what I needed) ! Do you have an original reference for the Back-and-Forth result ?

Comment: It’s in the link, which is worth reading on its own. (A quick read.)

Comment: Or do you mean the transfinite argument for the generalization of Cantor’s theorem? The Wikipedia article has several links, which I haven’t followed. However, the proof is a completely straightforward adaptation of the usual argument. Since you’re familiar with transfinite induction, you should have no problem doing it.